# Make new rows in Pandas dataframe based on df.str.findall matches?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `current_df` I want to create a new row for each regex match that occurs in each entry of `column_1`. I currently have this below:

`current_df['new_column']=current_df['column_1'].str.findall('(?<=ABC).*?(?=XYZ)')`

This appends a list of the matches for the regex in each row. How do I create a new row for each match? I'm guessing something with list comprehension, but I'm not sure what it'd be exactly.

The output df would be something like:

```
    column_1                                                                 column2        new_column
    ABC_stuff_to_match_XYZ_ABC_more_stuff_to_match_XYZ...                    data           _stuff_to_match_
    ABC_stuff_to_match_XYZ_ABC_more_stuff_to_match_XYZ...                    data           _more_stuff_to_match_
    ABC_a_different_but_important_piece_of_data_XYZ_ABC_find_me_too_XYZ...   different_stuff _a_different_but_important_piece_of_data_
    ABC_a_different_but_important_piece_of_data_XYZ_ABC_find_me_too_XYZ...   different_stuff _find_me_too_
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `extractall`, and with `merge`:

```
df.merge(df.column_1.str.extractall('(?<=ABC)(.*?)(?=XYZ)')
           .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True),
         left_index=True,
         right_index=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extract` function.

```py
df['new_column'] = df['column_1'].str.extract('(?<=ABC).*?(?=XYZ)', expand=True)
```